# trying to get CSS3 spotlight effect working with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch

I'm trying to get this effect to work with touch events on an ipad, here is what it should look like with mouse events on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FwsV4/1/

This is what I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/FwsV4/3/ which isn't working for me.

To be honest I'm a little lost with touch events and how to translate mouse clicks/moves to them. I'm actually not sure how to best utilise this effect, but I want to keep the elements underneath interactive using touch start/end events.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you will need to bind to touchstart to prevent the page from scrolling. You could just do:

```
$('myElement').htmlElement.bind("touchstart", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
);
```

It's probably better to get the co-ords from this as well though.

Here is a good tutorial on touch events:
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

Your second problem is setting the element to 5000px height and width, as by default iOS will zoom to include the entire page. You should adjust this OR use the viewport tag to change zoom behaviour (see [viewport apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)).

The following code is also incorrect and returns a Boolean value, not one of the objects.

```
  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
```

This should be:

```
 var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] ? e.originalEvent.touches[0] : e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
```

**BUT** with touchmove you're interested in e.originalEvent.touches[0] (assuming only single finger touch events are of interest).

You should also avoid using inline js and separate file js in this manner (there are reasons to do so in some circumstances perhaps). It makes it harder to follow.

I'm not sure using touch events with jfiddle is a great plan either (I might be wrong), i'd just use a normal webserver/local files to develop on.

Comment: Thanks for all that, sorry i should have said the jsfiddle link is just a hasty example for the purposes of getting help on here. I'm going to look in to what you suggested now.